# Custom Authorize attribute for Facebook

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to create a custom Authorize attribute for my MVC 3 application. I know that there is a default FacebookAutorize attribute that checks if the user is logged in. The reason why I want to create a Custom attribute is that the user is able to create an account with Facebook or without (default membership) Facebook.

Now when the user is logged into facebook I want to get the connected membership account and call the FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie method to login.

When I run my application in VS2010 (F5) the user is not logged in so you get the login page. When I click the login button and redirect to the homecontroller index action I see in the custom attribute that the FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthenticated() methoded is true.
After I close the browser and hit F5 again in VS the website is navigated to the homecontroller index again. In that moment the custom authorize is called again and I see that the FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthenticated() returnes false.

Why is it false? I was already authenticated right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

download the latest source code and checkout "CS-AspNetMvc3-WithoutJsSdk.sln" sample which demonstrates the use of FormsAuthentication and Facebook OAuth.